How to call Azure API from an Angular app, hosted in Static Web App with impersonation
I'm developing a very very basic Angular app. It just has to display in a nice way the files and folder, from an Azure Storage, for the current user.
I've followed all the tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization
So basically:

I've the app hosted as a static web app
I redirect /.auth/login/aad to login
I call /.auth/me to know if the current user is logged on

But now I wish to be able to call the Azure API to get the list of azure storage blob:
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list

But in order to do this, I've to provide the authorization bearer, which I don't find in the response of /.auth/me, as described here
How do I get this token based on this azure static web authentication?

Well, as of today, that doesn't seems to be possible, according to this github issue
The option everybody seems to do is to use instead an Azure App Service + msal.js(in my case @azure/msal-browser + @msal-angular but there are version for other framework), even if I'm not totally sure why msal.js could not be used directly with Static web apps.
